# Extra brackets while writing to flat file

Tags: python, pandas

I Use following code to write to flat file

```
code = np.unique(from_csv['code'])
      date_of_trade = np.unique(from_csv['date_of_trade'])
      columns = ['code','max_csv_value','min_csv_value','volume_csv_value','mean_csv_value','date_of_trade']
      df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
      df.loc[len(df)]=[date_of_trade,code,max_csv_value,min_csv_value,volume_csv_value,mean_csv_value]
      with open("D:/file.csv", 'a') as f:
         df.to_csv(f, header=False,index=False)
```

The file contain extra bracket around code and date_of_trade in flat file

```
['2015-12-23']  ['1AL']
```

How can I avoid that?

Comment: You're constructing your df in a strange way, when do `np.unique` this creates an array but you then set the first row to take this as the data element in `df.loc[len(df)]=[date_of_trade,code,max_csv_value,min_csv_value,volume_csv_value,mean_csv_value]` You should just do `df['code'] = code` or pass a dict of the column names with arrays as key values to the df constructor

Comment: never mind you answer my question Thanks. I just put [0] and it work fine now @EdChum